# Method not working completely? What could be the error?

Tags: java, variables, runtime-error, development-environment

I was just working on some project and I could not find out what's wrong with the following code :

```
double getInterest(double amt,double tax){  
        double diff=0;
        double refund=0;
        double interest=0;
        if(amt>=(tax*0.4)){
           diff=amt-(tax*0.4);
           System.out.println(" "+diff);  //This is not working.Nothing gets printed.
           refund=diff;                   //The value is not being assigned to refund.
        }                                 //refund remains to be 0 throughout.
         interest=diff*0.01*12;
         if(refund>0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your refund is: "+refund);
         }
        return interest;
}
```

I can't figure out any error in the code. But it is still not working completely.
The errors are given in the code in the form of comments.
Anyone help me to figure out the errors and reslove the issue?

I don't know why the value of `diff` is not getting printed and why the value of `diff` is not being assigned to the variable `refund`.

I'm working in NetBeans and it's not giving any kind of compile-time error.

I've tried to check the values by using the `println` for both `diff` and `refund` But the values are not getting printed.

Comment: There is certainly a compiler error! There is a bracket missing in the test `if (amt >= (tax * 0.4) {` and `interest` is not declared. Is this the _real_ code?

Comment: For one thing, never use double type for representing money.

Comment: Sorry i just typed it in the editor and forgot to declare interest and give the bracket. And I'm pretty sure there isn't any compiler error. As NetBeans would give an error when I try to run the code. But it is not giving any error and there isn't any error symbol in the editor.

Comment: Just debug the code and add a breakpoint on the `if` statement. And check what is the value of both the variables. These kinds of problem you should resolve on yor own.

Comment: Did you checked what values are you passing to this method and are they meeting the if criteria to enter into the if block. Print the amt and tax before if and see.

Comment: @RohitJain I know this is not linked with the question but can you tell me why I should not use the double datatype for money?

Comment: @GCJavaDeveloper The values haven't anything wrong. The code is calculating the `interest` and `return`ing it. But the value of `diff` is not getting assigned to `refund`.

Comment: A debugger is a fine thing.

Comment: I can run your code correctly if I pass the correct values meeting the if criteria. So doesn't seems to be issue with code, it only looks like that the if condition is not getting full filled. And as you said if this is assignment issue then atleast your sysout should be printed

Comment: @GCJavaDeveloper I have also tried using the values meeting the criteria but it's not printing the values.

Answer (score 0):

Well if the statements in the `if` block are never executed, that implies that there is never a call to this method where the arguments meet the condition `amt >= (tax*0.4)`. So the real question is, what values are you passing to this method?

Comment: The value are meeting the `if` condition. But the value of `diff` is not getting assigned to `refund`.

Comment: That means you should see the diff getting printed ?

Comment: @GCJavaDeveloper Nope! i just added it to check the value of `diff` but it's not getting printed.

Answer (score 0):

Your bracketing on the 
`if(amt>=(tax*0.4){`
line is missing a closing `)` bracket before the first `{` bracket. Make sure you check your bracketing and make sure you have all errors turned on in the options menu (if you can).

This code should not compile because of the bracketing error. Check that Netbeans is compiling the right project as this should go crazy at compile time.

Comment: It's compiling. I just forgot to give the `)` while typing the code in this editor. And I'm still pretty sure there isn't any compiler error.

Comment: I can only think to do what @Rohit has stated and use the debugger, it may well be with your input values.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use the [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) type when dealing with currency to avoid [double precision issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

Here is the code rewritten in `BigDecimal`

```
BigDecimal getInterest(final BigDecimal amount, final BigDecimal tax) {
    BigDecimal diff = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    BigDecimal refund = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    BigDecimal reducedTax = new BigDecimal("0.4").multiply(tax);
    System.out.println("Amount is " + amount + ". Tax times 0.4 is " + tax + ".");
    if (amount.compareTo(reducedTax) >= 0) {
        diff = amount.subtract(reducedTax);
        System.out.println(diff);
        refund = diff;
    }
    BigDecimal interest = diff.multiply(new BigDecimal("0.01")).multiply(new BigDecimal("12"));
    if (refund.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your refund is: " + refund);
    }
    return interest;
}
```

Yes, I know it's much uglier. It will also be much slower. But it's new *correct*.

Onto your issue, presumably the code is not entering the `if` because `amount` was not greater than `tax * 0.4` - if you are sure that it was then maybe you have already encountered double precision issues.

I have added a `println` before the `if` so you can see what the values are before the test happens.

Comment: I have tested using the `println` but the values aren't getting printed.

Comment: What are you running on. They are getting printed _somewhere_ - it just depends where `stdin` is going.

Comment: I didn't get you by `stdin` ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `stdout` really. Where a program output goes when you do `println`. If you run from the command line then this is the command line, otherwise it can be anywhere. For example Tomcat intercepts `System.out` so everything ends up in Tomcat's logs.